# SharpSsh: Restart file transfer if current file transfer too slow?

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, .net-4.0, sftp

My code downloads a file from a remote server to our server.

Usually, one file takes, at most, about a minute to complete the download. But there are times that the download takes well over 5 minutes.

Is it possible to restart a download if the current download takes, say, over 5 minutes?

```
Tamir.SharpSsh.SshTransferProtocolBase sshCp;
sshCp = new Scp(sessionOptions.HostName, sessionOptions.UserName);
sshCp.Password = sessionOptions.Password;
sshCp.Connect();

foreach (UmtsFilesStruct u in Array)
{
    try
    {
        sshCp.Get(u.RemoteFilePath, u.LocalFilePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Logger._LogName))
        {
            string error = string.Format("error downloading file [{0}], Remote: {1} & Local: {2} ",
                ex.Message, u.RemoteFilePath, u.LocalFilePath);
            Logger.Log(error, w);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` as a timer. When `timer.Elapsed >= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)` close your connection and run your posted code again. If file would be downloaded less then 1 minute for an instance you must not forget to stop the timer and reset its value to zero to prevent downloading again when file actually was downloaded.

P.S. you can try `System.Timers.Timer` as well if you had problems with `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`